# SelectPDF HtmlToPDF linked Google webfonts not working

Tags: html-to-pdf, selectpdf

My application is a .NET 5 Web API that will run as an App Service on Microsoft Azure

Everything works fine except the custom font I am trying to use
I am trying to link a font from google in HTML and then convert this to pdf

The HTML head has this tag inside
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" />`

And the CSS looks like this

```
html,
body {
    font-family: Muli;
}
```

I have also tried using @font-face like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Muli';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v28/7Aulp_0qiz-aVz7u3PJLcUMYOFnOkEk40eiNxw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

I have also tried downloading the TTF file for the font and adding it to a blob storage container in Azure, and using the link to that file in @font-face

I have also tried to increase the Converter.Options.MinPageLoadTime to 2 seconds

Every single one of these options work on my local machine, but not in Azure

Are there any other options that I might have overlooked, or is there nothing else I can do?